# Getting error message, "You must install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime?"

Tags: macos

I'm getting the following error when trying to launch my application after upgrading Mac OSX:

[image]

The more info says to go [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) and download this file.

Comment: So go there and download the file, and run it. Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click "More Info…"
2. This will take you to [this page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).
3. Click "Download."
4. When it finishes downloading, run the installer.

tl;dr — literally just follow Apple's instructions and you should be set.